# Postgresql & Next.js & Vercel

Tags: postgresql, next.js, vercel

When I was building a PostgreSQL project, I was deploying it to Heroku, and working fine since I can easily add PostgreSQL.
But now I'm learning Next.js and using PostgreSQL on my local machine, If I deploy it to Vercel how should I handle PostgreSQL?

Comment: Vercel is a platform for serverless applications, so you would deploy your PostgreSQL database elsewhere!

Comment: Thanks leerob, I am now using Supabase as sn PostgreSQL provider.